# Magento: Load review form on external page

Tags: php, forms, magento

By default the Magento URL for the review form is like:

```
www.domain.com/(producturl)-reviews#review-form.
```

But in this page the review-form is a section in the reviews page.

I want to load the review-form in unique page with this URL:

```
www.domain.com/(producturl)-review-form.
```

This review-form will only be the form for this product.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: you need to make a custom extension for this.

Comment: @DeepKakkar And how should I do that?

Comment: what your mean by product url.... that format `review/product/list/id/410/category/14/#review-form`

Comment: @AmitBera What I mean is that I want to load this not as a anchor url on the same page. But I want to load the review form on a individual page

Comment: Can you put an example URL for current review URL and new new url

Comment: @AmitBera The current url is like www.domain.com/laptop1-reviews#reviewform. So the review form is displayed below all the reviews of that product. Just like it works by default on Magento. But I do not want to load the reviewform on the page With all the reviews, but on a entirely own page. I do not have a url for this, that is what I want to achieve. The url structure for the reviewform does not matter, I only do need to load it on its own page

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case,it  will `better idea` to  create custom route like `Mage_Cms` module.

Where depends on `request path using Custom route match`   `internally` set
the `request path`

- `modules ->Mage_Review`
- `controller  ->ProductController.php`
- `Action ->listAction.`

Customer will see that like

```
http://www.example.com/laptop1-review-form
```

but internally it hit to

```
http://www.example.com/review/product/list/id/33661/
```

**Here**

```
`laptop1` is  `product url_path` value
 `33661` is `product id` 

 `-reviews-form` suffix for review url as you want
```

1. create custom font router for this custom module

---

```
`<frontend>
    <routers>
        <productview> <!--  router identifire -->
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <module>Dev_Productreview</module>
                    <frontName>productreview</frontName>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </productview>
    </routers>
</frontend>`
```

[Refernce](http://www.atwix.com/magento/create-custom-router/)

2. Add an observer on controller_front_init_routers

---

```
<controller_front_init_routers>
        <observers> 
        <add_review_route>  <!-- observer identifier -->
            <class>Dev_Productreview_Controller_Router</class>
            <method>initControllerRouters</method>
        </add_review_route> 
        </observers>
    </controller_front_init_routers>

This observer add new routers 



public function initControllerRouters($observer){
        $front=$observer->getEvent()->getFront();
        $front->addRouter('productreview',$this);
        
    }
```

### 3.add router class

. Now you need `define router class at Controller folder not controllers folders`

Where using `match ()`   check the `request path match with your pattern (producturl)-review-form.` . check string  `review-form`  exits in  this `request path`() [reference](http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-router-in-magento/)

```
$requestPathInfo=trim($request->getPathInfo(),'/'); 
    if(strpos($requestPathInfo,'-review-form')==false):
            return  false;
        endif;
```

### 4.Get product url from request path and save it

If  request path contain  `review-form`  then  then save require an variable then remove `review-form` from  this string.

```
$producturl=str_replace('-review-form','',$requestPathInfo)
```

6. Check product exits in current store

---

Then using `$producturl` check this path for which `product`

```
$Rewrite=Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')
                    ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                    ->loadByRequestPath($identifier);
```

7. Set internal request Module,controller,Action name

---

If product is exits then  `module,controller,action for this request.` which will be hit

`Mage_Review` Module `ProductController`  at `listAction`

```
$request->setModuleName('review') 
            ->setControllerName('product')
            ->setActionName('list')
        ->setParam('id', $productid);
```

8. Finally now set  request alias  as `producturl-review-form` thus customer can only laptop1-review-form as review page.

Hope this will help you

you can get full module at [Github](https://github.com/devamitbera/magento-stackexchange/tree/master/Rewrite%20review%20url%20-MSE-69682)

**In this module i have make review like :**

```
http://YOurmagentoInstanceurl/linen-blazer-585.html-review-form
```

**whenerever product url is**

```
http://YOurmagentoInstanceurl/linen-blazer-585.html
```

Comment: Many thanks! I placed the full module of Github on my store. But where can I find the reviews and where can I find the review form? What are the URL's

Comment: suppose `linen-blazer-585.html` is product then you can this product review page by suffix add    `-review-form` end of product url ( `linen-blazer-585.html-review-form`)

Answer (score 0):

In your review-form phtml file, call directly the review block.

```
$this->getLayout()
 ->createBlock("review/product_view_list")
 ->setTemplate("review/product/view/list.phtml")
 ->toHtml();
```

You can find all block name and block template in xml layout files (example here : http://doc-magento.com/nav.html?app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/review.xml.source.html)

Comment: Thanks! But how do I get it on its own page then?

Comment: you must create a local module to configure routing (http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-3-magento-controller-dispatch/magento-for-dev-part-2-the-magento-config)

Comment: and add in method_block, layout (http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/custom-layouts-and-templates-with-magento--cms-21419) and finally your review-form.phtml with the call to default review block

Comment: Why ? have you any error message or unexpected behavior ?

Comment: No, I can get it done with the instructions. Can you give me an example code of the local module that should be created?

Comment: First, (step 1) you can create moudle strucutre with http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/

Comment: After, (step 2) you update namespace/module/etc/config.xml file with config shown in http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-3-magento-controller-dispatch/magento-for-dev-part-2-the-magento-config and finally (step 3) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30575631/magento-load-review-form-on-external-page/30729022?noredirect=1#comment49525237_30729022